# Вывод друзей пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть скрипт друзей, мне нужно вывести на странице друга данного пользователя. Есть база данных `frnds`, а в ней поля `id`, `user_one`, `user_two`. Есть страница http://test1.ru/friends/?id=1 там все показывает отлично, а на http://test1.ru/id1 показывает у всех пользователей одного и того же друга.

```
<?php
...
$query = "SELECT
            user_one,
            user_two
          FROM
            frnds
          WHERE
            user_one = '$myrow2[id]' OR
            user_two = '$myrow2[id]'";
$frnd_query = mysql_query($query);

while ($run_frnd = mysql_fetch_array($frnd_query)){

  $user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
  $user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];
  if ($user_one == $myrow2['id']) {
    $id = $user_two;
  } else{

  $id = $user_one;
  }
  $username = getuser($id, 'username');
  $family = getuser($id,'family');
  $avatar = getuser($id,'avatar');
  echo "<a href='/id$id'><div id='textop'>$username $family</div> ";
  echo "<img src='/".$avatar."' width=110px border=0px><br/></a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: у вас и не должно работать. читайте внимательнее про ЧПУ

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 1):

У вас вероятно на уровне сервера не настроены Rewrite преобразования http://test1.ru/id1 в http://test1.ru/friends/?id=1. Поэтому GET-параметр `id` остается не заполненным или получает значение по умолчанию в скрипте. Поэтому при использовании альтернативного URL вы всегда получаете одного и того же пользователя.